# Can't get the most simple knockout.js sample to work?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

This really bothers me. Please have a look at the [Hello World example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) of knockout.js.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script src="knockout-1.2.1.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Here's my data model
        var viewModel = {
            firstName: ko.observable("Planet"),
            lastName: ko.observable("Earth")
        };
        viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
            return viewModel.firstName() + " " + viewModel.lastName();
        });

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel); // This makes Knockout get to work
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems, that the binding doesn't work. If I `alert(viewModel.fullName());` I get "Planet Earth" as expected. But neither the input elements nor the span gets filled with data.

**What am I doing wrong?**

[Here](http://ahb.me/3Wuh) is a zip file which includes both my file and knockout.js

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your issue is that you are calling ko.applyBindings too soon.

You want to either move your script tag to the bottom or execute it in an onload or something like jQuery's ready function.

Answer (score 4):

Just add window.onload= function() in the beginning of script..

```
  window.onload= function() {

    // Here's my data model
    var viewModel = {
......
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel); // This makes Knockout get to work
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a working version of the KnockoutJs tutorial.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/monitor.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function WebmailViewModel() {
            // Data
            var self = this;
            self.folders = [ 'Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam' ];
            self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
            self.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();
            self.chosenMailData = ko.observable();

            // Behaviours    
            self.goToFolder = function(folder) {
                self.chosenFolderId(folder);
                self.chosenMailData(null); // Stop showing a mail
                $.get('/mail', {
                    folder : folder
                }, self.chosenFolderData);
            };
            self.goToMail = function(mail) {
                self.chosenFolderId(mail.folder);
                self.chosenFolderData(null); // Stop showing a folder
                $.get("/mail", {
                    mailId : mail.id
                }, self.chosenMailData);
            };

            // Show inbox by default
            self.goToFolder('Archive');
        };


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());">
    <!-- Folders -->
    <ul data-bind="foreach: folders">
        <li>
            The current folders are: <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>
        </li>
    </ul>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ko.applyBindings()` should called once the view gets loaded then the data gets binded to the controls automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Looking at the demos for knockout.js, you're missing one thing. You're not sending the view model as a parameter in to the dependentObservable function:

```
viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
        return viewModel.firstName() + " " + viewModel.lastName();
    }, viewModel);
```

Comment: That doesn't do the trick. And in the example, there is also no viewModel parameter for dependentObservable

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome:Mac and I got your exact code to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Appe/1/

Comment: @GísliKonráð It looks like the reason your code is working on the jsfiddle is because it is set to run the js library on load.

Answer (score -2):

If the values are not binding just fire up a check functionality before you make use of the array.
In knockout you can do this like

```
< !-- ko if:detail() -->


   --your HTML code to display the fields goes here--


 <!-- /ko -->
```