# KnockoutJS Databinding

Tags: knockout.js

I am facing similar issues with this post: [question]: [Can't get the most simple knockout.js sample to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154703/cant-get-the-most-simple-knockout-js-sample-to-work)

It's a simple news model with one title, and I would like to display it in an html span tag. I was able to do a js alert, which gave the right value, but the span tag does not display the value.

The answer of putting the applyBindings in the onload call didn't work. It was originally in the document ready function.

Here's a sample of the code:

HTML:

```
    Title: <span data-bind="text: Title"> </span>
```

JS:

```
function NewsItem(data) {
    this.NewsItemId = ko.observable(data.NewsItemId);
    this.Title = ko.observable(data.Title);
}

function NewsItemViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.NewsItemId = ko.observable();
    self.Title = ko.observable();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetNewsItemById",
        data: "{idstring:'1'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (results) {
            self.Title = results.d.Title;
            alert(self.Title);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new NewsItemViewModel());
});
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing the type and value of `self.Title` after your data call.

Try the following to set the `Title`:

```
self.Title(results.d.Title);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't realize there is so much difference between self.Title = results.d.Title;  and self.Title(results.d.Title);